# Hide Card Elements in Vue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-5.7, vue-filter

I've got a little question on how to do something like that:
I have 2 components (one for a Sidebar and one for my Cards (Bootstrap Cards))
The cards component gets rendered within a `foreach` loop directly from the database. There are 3 attributes: `title`, `description` and `category`.
Right now I want the sidebar to filter through that category and display all or only one category dynamically via Vue.
But I really don't know how. I'm new to Vue. I think I should use a `onclick` method but how to look for the right directory.

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    @include('includes.header')
    <body>
        <div id="app" class="wrapper">
            @include('includes.nav')
            @include('includes.headerPicture')
            <!--@include('includes.headerSidebar')-->
            <cards></<cards>
            @include('includes.footer')
        </div>
        <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the **CardComponent**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container sidebar-container">
            <ul class="nav justify-content-center nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/" style="color:white">Alle</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/livingspaces" style="color:white">Wohnraum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/therapies" style="color:white">Therapien</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/news" style="color:white">News</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/achievements" style="color:white">Erfolge</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/events" style="color:white">Events</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" v-for="card in cards">
            <img src="/img/card2.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{card.title}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{card.text}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            card: {
                title: '',
                description: '',
                category: '',
                text: ''
            },
            cards: [],
            validationErrors: '',
            uri: 'http://localhost:8000/cards/',
            isHidden: true
        }
    },

    methods: {
        loadCards() {
            axios.get(this.uri).then(response=>{
                this.cards = response.data.sortedData;
                this.loading=true;
            })
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.loadCards();
    }
}
</script>
<style>
.sidebar-container {
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
</style>
```

JSON Data:

```
{
sortedData: [
{
id: 1,
title: "Test2222",
description: "Test",
text: "Test",
category: "achievement",
created_at: "2019-01-17 15:56:14",
updated_at: "2019-01-25 12:25:26"
},
{
id: 2,
title: "TestView",
description: "asd",
text: "asd",
category: "achievements",
created_at: "2019-01-18 12:06:40",
updated_at: "2019-01-18 12:06:40"
},
{
id: 1,
title: "Test",
description: "Test",
text: "Testr",
category: "news",
created_at: "2019-01-16 16:05:51",
updated_at: "2019-01-16 16:05:51"
},
{
id: 1,
title: "Test",
description: "Test",
text: "Test",
category: "livingspaces",
created_at: "2019-01-16 16:31:53",
updated_at: "2019-01-16 16:31:53"
},
{
id: 2,
title: "Test",
description: "Test",
text: "Test",
category: "livingspaces",
created_at: "2019-01-17 15:55:48",
updated_at: "2019-01-17 15:55:48"
},
{
id: 3,
title: "Test",
description: "asdsadsadsadsadsdsdsadasdasdasdsadasdadsadsadasdsasadasdsadsadasdsads",
text: "Tesst",
category: "achievement",
created_at: "2019-01-28 15:15:20",
updated_at: "2019-01-28 15:15:20"
},
{
id: 1,
title: "Test",
description: "Test",
text: "Test",
category: "events",
created_at: "2019-01-16 16:43:05",
updated_at: "2019-01-16 16:43:05"
},
{
id: 1,
title: "Test",
description: "Test",
text: "Test",
category: "therapien",
created_at: "2019-01-16 16:42:35",
updated_at: "2019-01-16 16:42:35"
},
{
id: 2,
title: "TestFinal",
description: "Test",
text: "Test",
category: "therapies",
created_at: "2019-01-18 12:20:17",
updated_at: "2019-01-18 12:20:17"
}
]
}
```

Could you give me a hint or a little example on how to do something like that?

Comment: On what condition do you want hide a card?

Comment: If the category is news and i click on news in the sidebar only the news cards should be display and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bring your `app.js` code in the blade file otherwise you can't access the data fields.
Once you get your `app.js` code, create a `data` field `sCat: ''`. Then in your `card-component` use an `if` statement to see if the current category is equal to the sCat or sCat is equal to null. For ex:

```
<card-component title={{$data->title}} description={{$data->description}} category={{$data->category}} v-if="(sCat == {{$data->category}} || sCat === '')"></card-component>
```

A better approach would be to create a `master` component and put everything you have under the `id="app"` div, in the `master` component. This way you will have better control of your vue codes.

## EDIT

Approach 1:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
@include('includes.header')
<body>
    <div id="app" class="wrapper">
        <nav-component></nav-component>
        <header-component></header-component>
        <header-sidebar-component></header-sidebar-component>
            <div class = "container">
            <div class="row">
            @foreach ($sortedData as $data)
                    <card-component title={{$data->title}} description={{$data->description}} category={{$data->category}}></card-component v-if="(sCat == {{$data->category}} || sCat === '')">
            @endforeach
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    //Move your vue instance from app.js to here as below
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                sCat: '',
                ...
            }
            ....
        });
    </script
</body>
</html>
```

Approach 2 (recommended):

#### welcome.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
@include('includes.header')
<body>
    <div id="app" class="wrapper">
        <master card-items="{{ $data }}">
    </div>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Master.vue

```
template
    <nav-component></nav-component>
    <header-component></header-component>
    <header-sidebar-component></header-sidebar-component>
    <div class = "container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-x-y" v-for="item in items"> //add some column values if needed or use plain div
                <card-component :title="item->title" :description="item->description" :category="item->category" v-show="(sCat === item->category || sCat === '')"></card-component>
        </div>
    </div>
script
    import NavComponent from 'pathToNavComponent.js';
    //import other components
    props: {
        items: Array
    }
    components: {
        NavComponent,
        ... //other components imported
    }
    data: {
        sCat: '',
        ...
    }
    ...
```

Comment: And then trigger a onclick method? Can it access the Nav when i include it with a blade file in the welcome?

Comment: I have added examples for both approaches. Apologize if I had made any syntactical or typo errors, but you should get a brief idea what I am trying to say from the example.

Comment: Hey, but what to trigger then?

Comment: I did change the code like you see in my new example above. Its now getting the data dynamicly via the Component so whe can reach it from there not via props! No Problems with special chars and stuff and we can access everything from there directly. Only the filter method is left over for the project to finish at first

Comment: Great, but one suggestion, don't hard-code your `uri`, rather use some `.env` file to fetch base url. you can use something like `process.env` to read the `.env` file. Also, there's no `loading` field in `data` object, hence it will throw an error/warning.

Comment: No errors at all. But i still dont know how to filter the Data :X I know how to but i dont know how to display only the data i do want...

Comment: Did you try using a `v-if` or `v-show`? I have already given an example in my answer.

Comment: I tried using the v-show method. But i dont get your example^^ its not setting anything. What should it set to sCat?

Comment: Oops! I forgot about that. Actually sCat represents your selected category. Basically you have to bind an onClick event to this. Somthing like this: <a class="nav-link" href="/news" style="color:white" @click="sCat = 'news'">News</a>

Comment: Thats not really working^^ Its not getting or setting anything with ur example. We need to implement a filter or anything like that

Comment: I´ve postet you the form of the json data ill do get

Comment: checkout this pen: https://codepen.io/pkimtani/pen/xMENmp
I am using vuetify to quickly demonstrate my thoughts, is this something what you are looking for?
Also, I noticed an `href` in your nav-link, what's the purpose of it? Since you are using nav items only to filter cards, is an anchor link (href) required there?

Comment: Nope its not. I did indeed deletet it shortly afterwards and just used it like a button. Its working now thank you really much :)